# Java cast object to an interface that is not implemented but matches signature

Tags: java

Let say I have a class:

```
class A{
    void doSomething();
}
```

And also, I have an interface:

```
interface I{
    void doSomething();
}
```

Is it possible to cast object `A` as `I`?

```
A object = new A();
I objectInterface = (I) object;
```

I get an error `java.lang.ClassCastException: A cannot be cast to I`. Why does this occur and can I create a partial interface for an object that does not implement that interface? I do not have control of that class.

Comment: Casting is **not** a magical way of converting objects. There is no Java magic involved at all. It only changes the view to an object that already is of that type. For example a `Dog` can be casted to an `Animal` if `Dog extends Animal`. Because the `Dog` already is an `Animal`. It only means "*hey compiler, please forget about the fact that its actually a `Dog`, only keep that its an `Animal`*".

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You can see from the error message that you can't perform that cast. And the javadoc of `ClassCastException` states "Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance."

Comment: Are you thinking of something like Go where a type can satisfy any number of interfaces if it just defines method with a particular signature?

Comment: What is your real problem? What you mean by "partial interface" and "I do not have control of that class." ? Do you want to cast an external class to one of your interfaces? May be you can use proxy pattern or adapter pattern? Or just simply wrap class A with different class which implements the interface.

Comment: You can create a subclass of `A` that implements `I`: `class B extends A implements I {}` and provide an implementation for `doSomething()`

Comment: Class A is out of my control. It's published by a 3rd party. I dont want to modify it. I figure since my interface matches the object method signatures, there wouldnt be a problem. kinda like in C

Comment: Nope.  There is definitely a problem; you can't do that in Java.  You will have to work around it.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Not true. You can use reflection with dynamic proxies to "implement" some interface, by delegating calls to other objects.

Comment: I appreciate the accept ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because that is how Java works.

Java doesn't allow what other languages call "duck typing".

Meaning: a class X implementing all methods that belong to an interface Y is **not** sufficient for `someX instanceof Y` to return `true`.

Only when the class definition says `class X implements Y` that instanceof / cast are valid. When you can't change the class definition, then a *cast* is not possible.

One *solution* for you would be to look into reflection and [dynamic proxies](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies).

Meaning: when you have an interface Y, and you would know how to *delegate* invocations of interface methods (for example to methods of a an object of class X), then you can do that dynamically, using that proxy concept.

*Disclaimer*: as in everything that is based on reflection, such code is easy to get wrong, and hard to maintain over time. So follow that tutorial step by step, do a lot of research and ensure you really understand what you are doing! But it does work, and *many* interesting features of large frameworks such as spring make use of dynamic proxies.

Comment: Kudos for bringing up duck typing.  Java's not a dynamic language.

Comment: Aren't method references kind of "duck typing"? I mean they create interface instances based on objects that do not inherit from the interface. There are valid arguments against it but at this point half supporting it is weird and is frustrating, since you often don't have access to classes and interfaces.

Comment: @RedCrafterLP Well, method references reference ONE method, that's pretty limited. But interesting thought, I agree.

Comment: This could be a way to optimize the discussed proxy for functional interfaces. You could skip the proxy entirely if a FI is detected.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have control over class `A`, and you have to be able to use it as a polymorphic interface `I` at runtime, then you'll have to wrap it:

```
public class B implements I {

    private A a;

    public B(a) { this.a = a; }

    public void doSomething() { this.a.doSomething(); }
}
```

Comment: Or make `B` both `extends A` and `implements I`, and use a `B` object instead of an `A` object

Comment: You can extend; I prefer composition over inheritance when possible.

Comment: @GhostCat - a bridge too far for me.  I'll stick with my composition proposal.

Comment: I agree, it is a strange idea when you have never used it. But when you have to, and you know what you are doing, it turns out to be pretty helpful. There are many nice things that *only* exist because Java has this feature.

Comment: I would think somebody who failed to understand why this cast didn't work will struggle with reflection.  But you're correct, as always.